# How can i set the location of minor ticks in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw a grid on the x-axis in a matplotlib plot at the positions of the minor ticks but not at the positions of the major ticks. My mayor ticks are at the positions 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and have to remain there. I want the grid at 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5.

```
....
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
....
minorLocator   = MultipleLocator(0.5)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minorLocator)
plt.grid(which='minor')
```

The code above does not work since it gives the locations at 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, ... How can I set the positions of the minor ticks manually?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use [`matplotlib.ticker.AutoMinorLocator`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.AutoMinorLocator). This will automatically place N-1 minor ticks at locations spaced equally between your major ticks.

For example, if you used `AutoMinorLocator(5)` then that will place 4 minor ticks equally spaced between each pair of major ticks. For your use case you want `AutoMinorLocator(2)` to just place one at the mid-point.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator

N = 1000
x = np.linspace(0, 5, N)
y = x**2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, y)

minor_locator = AutoMinorLocator(2)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minor_locator)
plt.grid(which='minor')

plt.show()
```

[image: Example plot]

Using `AutoMinorLocator` has the advantage that should you need to scale your data up, for example so your major ticks are at `[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50]`, then your minor ticks will scale up to positions `[5, 15, 25, 35, 45]`.

If you really need hard-set locations, even after scaling/changing, then look up [`matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator). With this you can pass a fixed list, for example `FixedLocator([0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5])`.

Comment: @Ffisegydd will this method also work with dates `(DD/MM/YYYY)`?

Comment: can this be implemented without using the figure and subplots ? using plt alone ?

Comment: Beware! This will silently do the wrong thing if your major ticks are not equally spaced. You need to use `FixedLocator`. Also, that breaks if your ticks are dates, apparently you need to pass them through `matplotlib.dates.date2num` first (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37162866/3538165). Whyyyyyy....

Comment: @AyanMitra, with `plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator()` and similar.

Comment: Also take note that you are creating an instance `minor_locator` which is set here to an axis; you must create other instances to apply to other axes (y-axis for example).  I'd suggest:
`ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))`